# Extract month from the date in BATCH script

Tags: batch-file

I am writing one batch script in windows. I want to extract Month part from string `1/12/18` in format `m/dd/yy`. Here it is 1
Please help on this.

```
2/04/17 > 2
5/06/12 > 5
```

Comment: Use a FOR /F command to split the string apart by using the DELIMS option and the / as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

to split a string, use a `for /f` loop:

```
set "string=2/04/17"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=/" %%a in ("%string%") do set month=%%a
echo %month%
```

(Note: `tokens=2` will be Day, `tokens=3` will be `Year`)

Comment: Thanks , I will try and let you .